# What would happen if you connected two wireless NICs' antennas with one coaxial cable?

Tags: wireless-networking

Could you set up an ad-hoc network and essentially have a wired connection?

Comment: I'd say that's more of a http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ question.

Comment: The transmitted signal would swamp the opposing unit's receiver causing either damage or so much distortion that nothing could be decoded. Already been there with access points too close together to test a bridged wireless link. They needed separation before the receivers would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A direct coax connection over a short distance (say just 2-3m of cable) would be far too good of a conductor and would cause problems for the radios. It certainly wouldn't work, and could even damage the radios.

Many 802.11 radios can't maintain their highest data rates if the received signal strength (RSSI) is above -40dBm. Some radios transmit at as much as 30dBm. So you would need to provide as much as 70dB of attenuation in the 2.4GHz and 5GHz frequency bands. You can buy coax attenuators to do this, or you could look up or measure the attenuation characteristics of the type of coax you were going to use, and make sure to use a long enough length of coax to provide the 70dB of attenuation (maybe leave it on the spool).

Note that Wi-Fi antenna leads are generally 50ohm coax designed for low losses at 2.4 and 5 GHz. In contrast, TV antenna (and CATV) coax, is 75 ohm and optimized for traditional TV broadcast and cable TV frequencies, which are generally below 1GHz.